# Java 8: How to go through List with Lambda Expression

Tags: java, lambda

Until and including Java 7, it was usual to go through a list with this code:

```
for (String s : MapperContent.ZGONC) {
    mapper.mapZgonc(s);
}
```

From Java 8 on, there are Lambda Expressions available. My IDE, NetBeans, tells me, of course as a hint, to use a "functional operation".

How can I go through that list with the "new coding style"?

Comment: It depends on what you wish to do with your List.

Comment: `yourList.forEach(element -> System.out.println(element));`

Comment: @rzysia or simpler: `yourList.forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: Define "go through"! If you mean to execute some block of code for each element, with no side effect, then `.forEach()` is what you want, as the answers posted show. As it stands, it is really unclear what you really mean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
MapperContent.ZGONC.forEach(mapper::mapZgonc);
```

Comment: This works just perfect. Do you have any good reference or link where to get into that coding style with lamda expression?

Comment: @max.mustermann1 this is not a matter of coding style _at all_; it's a matter of understanding the different interfaces used in stream operations, and the fact that a lambda can be a method reference. First of all, please see what .forEach() accepts as an argument. Then investigate further.

Comment: Found a good explanation with this link:
http://thediscoblog.com/blog/2014/03/25/java-8-s-functional-fomentation/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just execute some operations depending on your list values you can do this like below :

```
Stream.of(MapperContent.ZGONC).forEach(el -> {
    mapper.mapZgonc(el);
});
```

Stream API has also other usefull functions like map, reduce, filter, collect.